# spark cross join eliminate duplicate

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I'm trying to figure out how to eliminate duplicates in cross join given two dataset.

For example client (clientDs)

```
clientDs = sc.parallelize(List('c1', 'c2', 'c3'))

clientMatrixDs = clientDs.join(clientDs)

clientProduct.show()

 -- output

 c1, c1
 c1, c2
 c1, c3
 c2, c1
 c2, c2
 c2, c3
 c3, c1
 c3, c2
 c3, c3
```

In this case,
both (c1,c2) and (c2,c1) are duplicates and I need to de-dupe it

I'm not sure how to do this

Looking for some ideas here.

Comment: How can you get `(p1, c1)` as the result of this join? Are clients and products of the same type? Usually, duplicates cannot arise in a join if they weren't any in the initial collections to begin with.

Comment: @CyrilleCorpet yeah, I just updated the example. thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your example, you have a bunch of `Tuple2[String, String]`s, and the problem is that you want an equality that `Tuple2` just doesn't have where `(a, b) == (b, a)`. This is why `distinct` doesn't work for you. You therefore have to provide your own custom equality.

The thing is you don't want to override `Tuple2`'s version of `equals` because that can be dangerous, so you can provide a custom equals somewhere:

```
def customEquals(tuple1: (String, String), tuple2: (String, String)) = {
  tuple1 == tuple2 || (tuple1._1 == tuple2._2 && tuple1._2 == tuple2._1)
}
```

Then you can use this function in a `filter` to get rid of your custom definition of duplicates:

```
val deduped = clientMatrixDs.filter {
  var seq = Seq.empty[(String, String)]
  tuple =>
    if (seq.exists(customEquals(tuple, _))) {
      false
    } else {
      seq :+= tuple
      true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`RDD`s have a method `distinct()`, which should work as the equivalent on, say `List`. I don't know about its performances, however.

**EDIT**

However, this won't work since `(a, b) != (b, a)` in scala. So you have to swap some of your elements to make sure you don't get any doubles.

If you have some ordering on your type, you can map all your pairs to their ordered equivalent. For instance, map `(2, 1)` to `(1, 2)` and `(3, 4)` to `(3, 4)`. Then you can use `distinct`, which will remove all duplicates.

```
val distinctPairsRDD: RDD[(T, T)] = rdd.map{
  case (a, b) if a <= b => (a, b)
  case (a, b) => (b, a)
}.distinct()
```

If you do not have such an ordering, you may replace your pairs by some `Set`s, which are unordered. So you can map your `RDD` as follows:

```
val distinctRDD: RDD[Set[T]] = rdd.map {
  case (a, b) => Set(a, b)
}.distinct()
```

However, this will lose the type you had, so you may need to go back to pairs after that. To do so, remember that `Set` themselves do not have duplicates, so if you had a pair with the same element twice, it will be mapped to a set with only one element.

So you must do the following:

```
val distinctPairs: RDD[(T, T)] = distinctRdd.collect {
  case Set(a) => (a, a)
  case Set(a, b) => (a, b)
}
```

The `collect` could be replaced by a `map`, but it may induce some MatchError if you change your code later on. This makes all other cases (if you happen to have an empty set or a set with more that two elements) to be discarded, so make sure of what you prefer on future changes (rather a RuntimeError, or discarded elements).

**TL;DR**

Try to order the element in your pairs, to get unicity. If this does not work use `Set`s, but it will be more complicated.